# How to take user entered search value as reference

Tags: php

Initially user enter a search value. On basis of that i have show him remaining php pages.
 I want to take that variable as Global. I tried with

> $GLOBALS["foo"]

It didn't worked.
Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

- use session variables
- store that value in a cookie
- store that value in the database

---

Basically you start a session and store your variable in the $_SESSION array, i.e:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
```

You need to start the session in every page in order to retrieve the value.

See the reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php